# How to create a PDF file with UWP C#?

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, uwp

I want to create a PDF file using C# for UWP, but the iTextSharp doesn't work for UWP, and I can't find any other 3rd party library that could create PDF files for UWP. Any suggestions?

Comment: If the files are basic here's a link on creating the PDF yourself - it's in VB but shouldn't be hard to convert : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2013/08/15/how-to-generate-pdf-on-windows-phone-in-vb-or-c.aspx

Comment: You should ask your question here: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ Also in the comment list of the article in the link above you'll find libraries that work with UWP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try Syncfusion, they have library for PDF creation, they even have a PDF Viewer control for UWP.

http://www.syncfusion.com/products/uwp

Comment: I tried Syncfusion, but the documentation doesn't match the actual code, e.g. I tried to save a PDF with PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument; <some stuff> document.Save("output.pdf"); It appears that it needs a stream, so I added a stream (document.Save(stream);), but nothing is saved...

Comment: The web site doesn't answer this (at least not explicitly): Is the PDF library implemented using .NET, as opposed to a native Universal Windows Runtime Component?

Comment: Judging from I can use their PDF lib by just adding/referencing .DLL to my UWP Project, it's compiled using .NETCore.

Comment: I see here some limitations on the pdf product of syncfusion. If I'm not wrong, we can't create pdf with custom fonts and styles. For dynamic charting there is no possibility too. Have you tried one of this, is this possible? Thank's!

Comment: @dachibox You should send query to Syncfussion support, I'm using their UWP suite but not using it's PDF library.

Answer (score 1):

There is also XFINIUM.PDF, it supports UWP.
http://xfiniumpdf.com/xfinium-pdf-crossplatform/xfinium-pdf-overview.html

Disclaimer: I work for the company that develops this product.

Comment: On xfiniumpdf exist some predefined charts to dynamically pass some json values and show on the pdf? Can we create an pdf with custom font and styles? Is there a possibility to load an pdf form and fill it or modify (adding images or text)? Thank's If you want more on twitter @dachibox.

Comment: @dachibox Custom fonts and styles are supported, fill and edit PDF is also supported by XFINIUM.PDF library. No integrated chart engine at this moment, you have to generate the charts as images and insert the images in the PDF.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use `FileSavePicker();` to save the PDF document to disk once you saved in to the memory stream.

```
PdfDocument document=new PdfDocument();
PdfPage page=document.Pages.Add();
document.Save(stream);
document.Close(true);
```

Note: these API's from syncfusion PDF Library.

Disclaimer: I work for syncfusion